# Calling javascript function on key up event in ASP.net MVC Razor code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following razor code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.quantity, 
new { id = "quantityBox", onkeyup = "CallTxtEvent()" })
```

This code calls a javascript function which I have shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallTxtEvent() {
        var value;
        value = document.getElementByID("quantityBox");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```

This function is not getting invoked with it is supposed to be. I checked the function with an `alert` alone and it worked. When I modify it with the above function it's not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you made a typo in your code:

```
value = document.getElementByID("quantityBox");
```

Should be:

```
value = document.getElementById("quantityBox");
//                            ^
```

Comment: With the brackets the function's getting called when I remove them it's not.

Comment: @RandomUser: ooh, I see the problem, it's not the reference. Editing, just a moment.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I need to do math operations with the value from the field quantityBox, should I case it before working it or how can I work with the value. Say I need to do **quantity * price**

Comment: Just use something like: `value = parseInt(document.getElementByID("quantityBox").innerHTML, 10);`. You can then work with `value` as you would any other integer.

Comment: @RandomUser: It should, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you can add class

`@class = "keyUpRemovePassw"`

and in your javascript call whit jquery

```
    $(".keyUpRemovePassw").keyup(function () {
        alert("keyup");
    });
```